# FindMaximum failing on a trivial problem

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, constraint

I am trying to solve a trivial optimization problem with `FindMaximum` but for some reason it is not going.
I reduced the problem down to the following non-working example:

```
FindMaximum[{ nx *  wx , nx <= 5 && nx ∈ Integers && wx <= 0.5},
  {{nx, 3}, {wx, 0.1}}]
```

In this form, the code returns the error:

> Constraints in {nx ∈ Integers, nx <= 5, wx <= 0.5} are not all equality or inequality constraints. With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported

Which doesn't seem to be true. When I convert the multiplication `*` to addition `+` in the objective function, which makes my code look like:

```
FindMaximum[{ nx +  wx , nx <= 5 && nx ∈ Integers && wx <= 0.5},
  {{nx, 3}, {wx, 0.1}}]
(* {5.5, {nx -> 5, wx -> 0.5}}  *)
```

The code works and I get the above stated answer. Am I missing something major?

I tried with a fresh kernel, and I got the same behavior.

My optimization problem is more complicated (so I need the multiplication and I also have non-linear constrains), but this is a minimal example to demonstrate the issue.

**Update:** I tried `FullForm[HoldForm[ .. ]]` on both expressions, they both have identical structures, except for the `Plus` and `Times` functions.

**Update2:** As GuessWhoItis suggested, `NMaximize` seems to work on this problem as follows:

```
NMaximize[{ nx   wx , nx <= 5 && nx ∈ Integers && wx <= 0.5},
  {{nx, 0, 3}, {wx, 0.0, 0.1}}]
(*{2.5, {nx -> 5, wx -> 0.5}} *)
```

Could this be a bug in `FindMaximum`?

Comment: What if you use `NMaximize[]` instead?

Comment: It does work with `NMaximize` ... (??)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: They are not equivalent. One `NMaximize` searches for a **global** maximum

Comment: I believe it's switching to `LinearProgramming` in the `Plus` case

Comment: And it's solving this equivalent problem `LinearProgramming[-{1, 1}, {{}}, {}, {{-Infinity, 
   5}, {-Infinity, .5}}, {Integers, Reals}]` . Of course it can't switch in the `Times` case ...

Comment: @belisarius Very good point about switching to linear programming. Could it still be trying to do the same in case of Times and hence it fails? Is `FindMaximum` supposed to solve this kind of problems or not (whether if finds local or global optimum)? Even the error message is bluntly wrong in this case ...

Comment: @Bichoy `FindMaximum` is  a black box. No way to spelunking inside it :(

Comment: In all cases, I think it should be filed as a bug for wolfram ...

Comment: (1) It's not a bug. (2) As the error message states, domain constraints such as integrality are only supported in `FindMinimum` for linear programming. (3) The change from `*` to `+` made it into a linear problem. As others have noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and as the error message says, `FindMaximum` only accepts integer domain constraints for linear optimization problems, while of course `nx * wx` is a non-linear term.

For ILP problems, `FindMaximum` uses a specialized solver from the COIN-OR branch-and-cut (CBC) library. `NMaximize` is using a different approach.